# how to get the text to go to the next row in a csv?

Tags: php, csv

i am trying to get the text to go to the next row in a csv. this works great for TXT but doesnt foe CSV. do i need to write something diffrent for the csv rows?

```
   <?php
   $fp = fopen('wo.csv', 'a'); 
   fwrite($fp, '"' . $_POST['Customer'] . '","' . $_POST['Contact_Name'] . '","' . "\r\n"); 
   fclose($fp);   
   echo "<h1>Thank you for doing business with!</h1>";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in CSV functionality!

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, array($_POST['Customer'], $_POST['Contact_Name']));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Reference**

- [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)
- [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: is the array like the custome, and contact_Name

Comment: i have seen this before just not sure what to do with it?            $list = array (
           array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
            array('123', '456', '789'),
          array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')

Comment: @Joe Gardner I've updated my answer to directly relate to your sample code